# How to format the float number to decimal number(7) using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have tried with `value.tofixed(7)`.

When I'm giving int value(3) its returning decimal (7) (e.g) 3.0000000.
At the same time if I give a float value(3.3) its returning decimal(6) (e.g) 3.300000

How to solve this?

Comment: I want for both. If i give int decimal should be 7  & for float also its should be  7 For(e.g) If i give 7 its should be 7.000000 &  If i give 7.3 its should be 7.3000000.

Comment: can you share sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: what do you want exactly? You can use `parseInt(3.3)`  to convert it to integer 3. Is that what you want? As per your comment, I think `parseInt()` will solve your problem, it will return 3 for both 3.3 and 3.

Comment: If `num.toFixed(7)` is only giving you decimal precision of 6 your javascript needs to beFixed.

Comment: toFixed() returns a string, not a numeric value.

Comment: Check This [It_is_correct_for_me](https://jsfiddle.net/g3uwdhoa/).

Comment: in code level i have written value.tofixed(7).  On screen when i am giving int value of 1 its showing 1.0000000 (decimal 7 digits) its right. but for floating number 1.1 its showing  only 1.100000 (decimal 6 digit) its supposed to be 1.1000000(decimal 7 digits). how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 3.300000 has 6 decimal places because of the code rounded one 0 to place the 3.

> - try this:

```
var value = 3;
var n = value.tofixed(7);
```

and

```
var value2 = 3.30;
var n = value2.tofixed(7);
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use :
- Math.floor() : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Math/floor.
- or Math.ceil() : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Math/ceil
Instead of toFixed().
There is another method called Math.round() which makes the round (upper or lower depending of the number you round) automatically without asking you about the floor/ceil param'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use toFixed() which return a fixed number of decimal point value (rounded). You can also use value.toPrecision(x) which will return x number of total digits.